# Line numbers don't show in aptana plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aptana, line-numbers

In the Aptana plugin for Eclipse, line numbers do not show (in Aptana components, such as Pydev, not in Eclipse components). Below is a screenshot of the HTML editor provided by aptana (notice the lack of line numbers):

[image]

And to show that it isn't an Eclipse problem, here is a markdown editor (provided by Eclipse). Notice the line numbers:

[image]

Any ways to fix this issue? I tried changing Aptana themes, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the image @lkjoel pasted on a high contrast display (or zoom in), you can see that the line numbers are indeed there, they're just very similar in color to the gray margin.

To change the color of the numbers (to something other than gray), go to:

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors. Change the "Line number foreground"

Answer (score 3):

Right-click the left ruler bar (a little bit left to the editor's folding annotations) and a menu should appear.

Click the "Show Line Numbers" and you should be set.

Comment: It is selected. I also tried unselecting and reselecting, but the same issue stays...

Comment: Time to file a bug with Aptana, then.

Comment: Which version are you on? Did you turn on word-wrap?

Comment: I decided to just remove it and use other plugins instead. I've had too many problems with Aptana